# Solution for IEnumerable.Contains() in entity framework linq queries

Tags: c#, entity-framework

I am been using entity framework for my application. Unfortunately I can't make expressions like this one in entity framework:

```
List<MyUser> users = (from user in database.MyUsers
                      join app in database.MyApplications 
                          on user.ApplicationId equals app.Id
                      where app.Name == this._applicationName 
                          && user.MyRoles.Contains(existingRole)
                      select user).ToList();
```

Any other approaches to this one. I don't want to change my database or my models. In my case the relationship between MyUser and MyRole is many to many with a glue table.

This is how the MyUser class is declared:

```
public partial class MyUser
{
    public MyUser()
    {
        this.MyApiTokens = new HashSet<MyApiToken>();
        this.MyLandingPages = new HashSet<MyLandingPage>();
        this.MyPresentations = new HashSet<MyPresentation>();
        this.MySlides = new HashSet<MySlide>();
        this.MyUserSettings = new HashSet<MyUserSetting>();
        this.MyRoles = new HashSet<MyRole>();
    }

    public System.Guid Id { get; set; }
    public string UserName { get; set; }
    public string Password { get; set; }
    public string EmailAddress { get; set; }
    public int ApplicationId { get; set; }
    public System.DateTime CreateDate { get; set; }
    public System.DateTime LastActivityDate { get; set; }
    public System.DateTime LastLockoutDate { get; set; }
    public System.DateTime LastLoginDate { get; set; }
    public System.DateTime LastPasswordChangedDate { get; set; }
    public string PasswordQuestion { get; set; }
    public string PasswordAnswer { get; set; }
    public string Comment { get; set; }
    public bool IsLocked { get; set; }
    public bool IsApproved { get; set; }

    public virtual ICollection<MyApiToken> MyApiTokens { get; set; }
    public virtual MyApplication MyApplication { get; set; }
    public virtual ICollection<MyLandingPage> MyLandingPages { get; set; }
    public virtual ICollection<MyPresentation> MyPresentations { get; set; }
    public virtual ICollection<MySlide> MySlides { get; set; }
    public virtual ICollection<MyUserSetting> MyUserSettings { get; set; }
    public virtual ICollection<MyRole> MyRoles { get; set; }
}
```

Comment: It's possible to use `Queryable.Contains` with entity framework. What error message to you get? What is the type of `user.MyRoles`?

Comment: in the code it is a ICollection<MyRole>

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Assuming MyRoles is an association property in the entity model (i.e. maps to a table), you may want to make the matching explicit on the primary key of the role object. For example:

```
user.MyRoles.Any(r => r.RoleId == existingRole.RoleId)
```

There isn't enough information in your question to give an exact answer, though.

Comment: this is the definition of the property : public virtual ICollection<MyRole> MyRoles { get; set; } in the MyUser class

Comment: Thanks - can you move that to your question & format as code to make it easier to read?

Comment: I added the entire class definition in the original post

Comment: Great - can you try using `Any`?

Comment: small question, will it work if the database is big? I mean I ran into a lot of problems with LINQ to SQL in some cases when it brought the entire tables into the memory and compared them there which it was slow. Will the query that you suggested only make an SQL in the database without further processing them afterwards.

Comment: Alecu, the best way to find out is to look at the actual query being sent to the database. You can try to use [IntelliTrace](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/magazine/ee336126.aspx) for that. If I'm correct, in this case the `Any` expression will be translated into an `EXISTS IN SELECT (...)` clause which does not fetch data from the SQL for the comparison, and should be fine. Whether or not that is optimized enough for what you consider a big database, is a separate question.